# What is the purpose of the psa decorator and how do we use it?

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I've been using `python-social-auth` for a few weeks in a Django project. Now I am reaching the point where I need to authenticate a user from a view (that is, not through the template tags such as `social:begin`) and [the documentation](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token) makes use of the `psa()` decorator from `social.apps.django_app.utils`.

I was not able to find anything that clearly explains what the `psa` decorator is supposed to do and the source from [omab/python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/apps/django_app/utils.py) does not provide any comment.

Can anyone explain:

1. What is the `psa` decorator supposed to do exactly?
2. What happens behind the scene when I use it to authenticate a user based on the access token retrieved by the front-end (possibly from any social network such as Facebook)?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code for psa (from [here](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/apps/django_app/utils.py)):

```
def psa(redirect_uri=None, load_strategy=load_strategy):
def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(request, backend, *args, **kwargs):
        uri = redirect_uri
        if uri and not uri.startswith('/'):
            uri = reverse(redirect_uri, args=(backend,))
        request.social_strategy = load_strategy(request)
        # backward compatibility in attribute name, only if not already
        # defined
        if not hasattr(request, 'strategy'):
            request.strategy = request.social_strategy

        try:
            request.backend = load_backend(request.social_strategy,
                                           backend, uri)
        except MissingBackend:
            raise Http404('Backend not found')
        return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
return decorator
```

As a decorator, it augments the function that it decorates.

It's doing three things:

1. Setting request.social_strategy (this object is framework-specific, eg, Django).
2. Setting request.backend (this object is specific to the authorization backend, eg, Facebook) based on the incoming backend string argument (eg, "facebook").
3. Providing a redirect URI or URI name (which is then "reversed" to get the URI) and passing the URI off to the backend so it knows where to redirect to when the time comes.

The decorated function can conveniently access request.social_strategy and  request.backend and know that they will be set. See the Python Social Auth documentation for more information about what the [Strategy](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/strategies.html) and [Backend](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/backends/) are for.